# Oracle PL/SQL Stored Procedure Cursor for update

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I am trying to update the 'damage_amt' of cars by increasing the value by 'inc', but only for accidents that occurred in year 'year'.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE updateDMG(xyear VARCHAR2, inc NUMBER) AS
    CURSOR cur1 IS
        select a.DAMAGE_AMT
        from participated a join accident b
        on a.report_nr = b.report_nr
        for update;        
    p_dmg PARTICPATED.damage_amt%TYPE;
    p_year NUMBER;
    inc_dmg NUMBER;
BEGIN
    p_year:=xyear;
    inc_dmg:=inc;
    OPEN cur1;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur1 bulk collect INTO p_dmg;
        EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;           
        UPDATE PARTICIPATED
        SET damage_amt = damage_amt * inc_dmg
        WHERE p_dmg like xyear;
    END LOOP;    
    CLOSE cur1;    
END updateDMG;
/
EXEC updateDMG('08', 0.10);
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete exists prior
```

Obviously I am lacking knowledge on the syntax of this type of answer. Can anyone point out my error? I can't seem to find anything from searching.

EDIT: Was missing a / after END. Now it doesn't actually update the rows.

FINAL EDIT: Figured it out. I think some of my variables are unnecessary, but I could be wrong.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE updateDMG(xyear NUMBER, inc DECIMAL) AS
CURSOR cur1 IS
    select a.DAMAGE_AMT, extract(year from b.ACCIDENT_DATE)
    from participated a join accident b
    on a.report_nr = b.report_nr
    for update;

p_dmg PARTICIPATED.damage_amt%TYPE;
p_year NUMBER;
input_year NUMBER;
inc_dmg DECIMAL;

BEGIN
input_year:=xyear;
inc_dmg:=inc;
OPEN cur1;

    FETCH cur1 INTO p_dmg, p_year;


    MERGE INTO PARTICIPATED x
    USING ACCIDENT y
    ON (x.report_nr = y.report_nr)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET x.damage_amt = x.damage_amt * (1 + inc_dmg/100)
    WHERE extract(year from y.accident_date) = input_year;



CLOSE cur1;



END updateDMG;
/
EXEC updateDMG(2008, 10);
```

Comment: If this is all one script, you may just be missing a `/` between the final `END` and the `EXEC` call?

Comment: That worked to get past the error! I was able to fix some other syntax errors, I'll edit it in above. Now, it is not updating any rows since in my LOOP, the WHERE condition checks the year with LIKE, but the parameter I pass in my call doesn't use a %.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a database right now to fully check syntax, but I would suggest something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updatedmg (p_year NUMBER, p_inc DECIMAL)
AS
   l_next_year   NUMBER;
   l_from_date   DATE;
   l_to_date     DATE;
BEGIN
   l_next_year := p_year + 1;
   l_from_date := TO_DATE (p_year || '-01-01', 'RRRR-MM-DD');
   l_to_date := TO_DATE (l_next_year || '-01-01', 'RRRR-MM-DD');

   UPDATE participated pt
      SET pt.damage_amt = pt.damage_amt * (1 + p_inc / 100)
    WHERE pd.report_nr IN (SELECT ad.report_nr
                             FROM accident ad
                            WHERE ad.accident_date >= l_from_date
                                  AND ad.accident_date < l_to_date);
END updatedmg;
```

Its simple and that way you probably can make better use of indexes on tables.

I hope it helps.

Good luck!